# Displaying a text file on a webpage

Tags: java, web-applications

I'm new to coding and have decided to start my learning on Java. I've got NetBeans and have started to create a very basic web application. I'd like to be able to display values from a .txt file onto the webpage, and I've got this code to do so.

```
<%
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Cats.txt"));
String line;
while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
               {
out.println(line);
}
in.close();
%>
```

My text file is in the same folder as my src folder (As I've seen you need to  put the file)
However, whenever I navigate to the web page I get a FileNotFound error. I've tried placing the files path in the FileReader but that gives an error due to the backslashes.

If anyone could help I'd be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it's looking for the file in the src directory of your application you should just be able move the file there and it should read it. If you would like to direct to a specific path you need to tell the IDE to treat the '\' as a normal slash to do this you need to close it off by using two '\'s instead of one eg:

```
<%
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
FileReader("C:\\MYPATH\\MYPATH2\\Cats.txt"));
String line;
while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
           {
out.println(line);
}
in.close()
%>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! No idea why it wasn't reading from the same folder as src, but putting the path seemed to sort the problem. :)